# Is there any downside to using negative array indices in C?

Tags: c, performance

It's been fairly well-asked here if negative indices are *allowed* in C, but I'm curious of there is any performance downside to using this technique frequently.  For example, does it break the compiler's ability to use the base+offset indexing on some hardware platform somewhere, or confuse the optimizer, etc.

I ask because I have a lot of decoding routines with the signature of

```
decode_something(char *buffer, int buffer_size, int bit_position) {
    ...
    if (((bit_position + need_bits) >> 3) < buffer_size) {
       x= buffer[bit_position >> 3] ...
       bit_position += need_bits;
    ...
}
```

and I realized I can greatly simplify all that code if I use a pointer to the end of the buffer:

```
decode_something(char *buf_limit, int bits_remaining) {
    ...
    if (need_bits <= bits_remaining) {
        x= buf_limit[ -((bits_remaining+7) >> 3) ];
        bits_remaining -= need_bits;
    ...
}
```

(well, actually this example doesn't show how it gets "much" simpler, but you can extrapolate to all the cases where calling this function or saving the parse state only require two variables instead of three.)

Now I'm considering using this pattern throughout an entire library, but I wanted to know if there's some reason not to do that.

Comment: The syntax `foo[bar]` for any array is just sugar for `*(foo + bar)`. It shouldn't matter in the slightest whether `bar` is positive or negative. Personally, I would say that doing the pointer arithmetic explicitly rather than using an index would make your code clearer, but I guess that's preference.

Comment: @Roflcopter4 It might hinder optimisations done before syntax sugar is decoded. I haven't looked at any source code but it is a possibility given how badly GCC is coded. With Clang, it should be alright, I guess.

Comment: Why would there by _any_ optimizations done before sugar is decoded? Surely any compiler will build an AST before doing anything of consequence? (note: I'm not rising to that trollbait re: gcc)

Comment: @Roflcopter4 I'm aware of the equivalence of pointer math.  But I'm also aware that ```*(foo + (-bar))``` is not the same AST and might miss out on some kind of optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > *For example, does it break the compiler's ability to use the base+offset indexing on some hardware platform somewhere, or confuse the optimizer, etc.*

No. C language standard clearly define it:

From C11 Standard#6.5.6p8:

> 8 When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. If the pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the array is large enough, the result points to an element offset from the original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the resulting and original array elements equals the integer expression. In other words, if the expression P points to the i-th element of an array object, the expressions (P)+N (equivalently, N+(P)) and (P)-N (where N has the value n) point to, respectively, the i+n-th and i-n-th elements of the array object, provided they exist. ....

Just, in case, if you are not aware:

From C11 Standard#6.5.2.1p2, the definition of subscript operator:

> The definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2))).

Your another question:

> > *but I'm curious of there is any performance downside to using this technique frequently.*

It boils down to question - There are two number `a` and `b`, out of these two operations - `a + b` and `a - b`, which operation is faster than other.

It's not the language that dictate time for operations like addition, subtraction etc., but it's the underlying processor. If you are really interested in it, you have to dig down to the instruction set of underlying processor and compare the latency of respective instructions etc..

Comment: I was kind of asking a question that could only be answered by someone with positive knowledge of a performance problem, which isn't fair, so I'll accept this answer for as long as that doesn't hapen.

Comment: @MConrad If you're really that paranoid just examine the assembly code produced by the compiler for each version. I'd be willing to bet they'll be identical.

Comment: Not that I think it matters (in most cases) but assembly output has to be slightly different. Performance difference "per se" (in this case) is negligible but the order you access memory COULD greatly affect how CPU cache - and its access prediction - works. But that depends so much on the specific CPU architecture that it's not worthy to discuss here